# Packing external files into jar and then allowing code to perform operations on these packed files

Tags: java, intellij-idea

So I'm using IntelliJ IDEA and I've got my structure as follows:

[image]

So firstly, I want to be able to package the res folder with all my scripts inside the jar, and then when I run my program it can access the python scripts from inside the jar itself.

So far when I try running things on `res/test.py` it can't find the file.

**EDIT**: I've taken a look at an article which suggests getting the temporary files location using `System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")` and maybe copying the files to there using `Class.getResourceAsStream("/path/to/file")`

I'm not sure however if `Class#getResourceAsStream` is suitable for getting it from inside the jar to write it to the temporary location.

Comment: Did you try it? What did not work?

Comment: @Henry see the answer

Answer (score 0):

The code works when you check the file exists prior to executing the `Process`:

```
File f = new File("res/test.py");
System.out.println(f.exists()); // true
```